# Find a set of solutions for $y'=\sqrt{y^2-1},\ y(0)=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For the IVP $y'=\sqrt{y^2-1},\ y(0)=1$ I am supposed to find a set of solutions depending on $2$ parameters.

While I can easily find 2 different solutions $y_1(x)=1$ and $y_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x}+e^x)$ that solve the IVP I don't know how to bring parameters into this problem. How can any solution depend on a parameter when the starting value is given? And if no solution depends on any parameter, what's the trick to create a set of solutions depending on 2 parameters?

Comment: The RHS of the equation is not Lipschitz continuous at $y=0$, therefore, the solution is not assured to be unique. Maybe you can find a family of solutions satisfying the IVP based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=1$, $y'=0$ yields $y=1$, is consistent with the initial condition.

Then if $y\ne1$,$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}=1$$ and

$$\text{arcosh }y=x+c,$$ $$y=\cosh(x+c).$$

As said by Robert, we can switch (twice) between the two solutions:

$$y=\begin{cases}x<c_-\to\cosh(x-c_-),\\c_-<x<c_+\to1,\\x>c_+\to\cosh(x-c_+)\end{cases}.$$

where $c_-\le 0\le c_+$. These are your two constants.

Solutions with a single or with no switch are also possible.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what is going on here! So you just ignore the IVP for the solution generated by separation of variables which is okay because we glue it together with the constant solution in the necessary area.

Comment: @RedLantern: as you can check, all these solutions verity the ODE and the initial condition.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: your solution can be $1$ for a while and then switch to a translate of $y_2$.

Comment: I thought of this too. But doesn't have the solution to be continuous? Otherwise I could basically just write down $$y_{a,b}(x)=\begin{cases}y_1(x), & x\in[a,b]\\y_2(x),& \text{ else }\end{cases}$$.

Comment: Yes, you should make sure the solution is continuous.  That tells you which translate of $y_2$ to use.

Comment: But then they can only switch at the point $x=0$. How do I bring parameters in?